# How to implement Drill - Down Functionality for a Table and Graph in Zeppelin

Tags: analytics, apache-zeppelin, drilldown

We are switching from a conventional BI tool(OBIEE) to Zeppelin.

So as OBIEE has few in-built functionalities, mainly-the drill down, we are trying to implement something alike in Zeppelin.

We have configured Oracle database as JDBC-interpreter with Zeppelin.

So I have created few views using oracle interpreter(oracle SQL queries)

Now I want something like- For a table created by a sql query ex: Col1-Product_Type Col2-Tot_Count

1. The Prod_Type column values should be clickable
2. Once Clicked, It should show the detail level of that clicked Prod_Type in a table(i.e.that particular clicked value should pass as a filter to the next table), either in the same paragraph or different paragraph
3. I want to achieve this same with graphs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the drill-down values are known before in-hand or static, [Dynamic forms](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/dynamic_form/intro.html) can be used.

Example:

> %jdbc
>   SELECT extensions_installed, count(*) FROM extensions_installed where extensions_installed like '%${extension_name=google,google|jira}%'
>   GROUP BY extensions_installed

If the values are dynamic or have to queried in another table, it is tricky but can be done using [Zeppelin Context](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/zeppelin_context.html) and [Object Interpolation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/other_features/zeppelin_context.html#object-interpolation).

Example: In the first paragraph, python or scala can be used to query the table and add the values to a zeppelin context variable

> %python
>   z.put("account_id",z.input("account_id"))

In the following paragraphs, zeppelin context variables can be used in queries

> %jdbc
>   SELECT npr from attributes WHERE account_id={account_id}